# React Native: How to open OS AutoFill settings under language in Android and iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, operating-system

How to I navigate user to Autofill settings under language and input when user click on a button using react native.

I have tried using

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native';
Linking.sendIntent('android.settings.SETTINGS.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS');
```

Along with that I even tried to call the following

```
     Linking.sendIntent('android.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE ').catch(
    e => console.log('EVent Messaga e', e),
    );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.